# Receiving Bus Error after trying to access data in void * from pipe

Tags: c, pipe, shared-memory, bus-error

I am currently writing a program to calculate the Lucas Series, Hexagonal Series, and Harmonic Series given a number from an input file. I am using a pipe and shared memory segment to share values across the programs.

I start by creating my pipe

```
int p[2];
if (pipe(p) < 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "Problem opening pipe!\n");
```

Then I run a child process to read the contents of the input file into my pipe where argv[1] is the name of the input file(maxPrime is used later but not here)

```
char tmpbuf[10];
char str[10];
sprintf(tmpbuf, "%d", p[1]);
pid = fork();
int maxPrime;
if (pid < 0) fprintf(stderr, "Error running child process\n");
else if (pid == 0) { // child
    close(p[0]);
    execlp("./Reader", "reader", argv[1], tmpbuf, NULL);
} else {
    wait(&status);
    close(p[1]);
    read(p[0], str, 10);
    printf("[Starter][%ld]: contents read from the read end pipe: %d\n", (long)prPid, atoi(str));
    n = atoi(str);
}
```

And finally, here is where I get the Bus error when trying to access a void pointer array called voidarr. This part of the program is where I am forking to the child processes to get the sums of the numbers in their respective series and print them to the standard output.

shms is an array of ints for file descriptors, voidarr is an array of void * for pointing to the shared memory, and pidArray is for storing the process ID of each child process

```
char *my_array[3] = {"lucas", "hexagonalseries", "harmonicseries"};
char *my_array2[3] = {"./lucas", "./hexagonalseries", "./harmonicseries"};
char *my_array3[3] = {"SHM_lucas", "SHM_hexagonalseries", "SHM_harmonicseries"};
char *my_array4[3] = {"Lucas.c", "Hexagonalseries.c", "Harmonicseries.c"};


for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if ((shms[i] = shm_open(my_array3[i], O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file descriptor!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((voidarr[i] = mmap(NULL, 32, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shms[i], 0)) == MAP_FAILED){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to map!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    pidArray[i] = fork();
    if (pidArray[i] < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error running child process %s", my_array[i]);
    } else if (pidArray[i] == 0) {
        execlp(my_array2[i], my_array4[i], my_array3[i], (char *) voidarr[i], NULL);
    } else { // parent
        //RECEIVING BUS ERROR ON LINE BELOW
        printf("[Starter]: %d and %s]\n", prPid, (char *)voidarr[i]);
        shm_unlink(my_array3[i]);
    }
}
```

This is what my output is

```
[Starter][1106394] : Created Shared memory "SHM_lucas" with FD: 3
[Starter][1106394] : Created Shared memory "SHM_hexagonalseries" 
with FD: 5
[Starter][1106394] : Created Shared memory "SHM_harmonicseries" 
with FD: 6
[Starter][1106394]: contents read from the read end pipe: 0
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Additionally, I don't know if this is needed to answer this question but here is my Reader.c

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) fprintf(stderr, "[Reader]: Wrong number of arguments, usage requires 2, found %d", argc - 1);
    int pipe_ref = atoi(argv[2]);
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File failed to open");
        return 1;
    }

    char buf[256];
    int run_sum = 0;
    int tmp = 0;
    printf("Hello from reader");
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f)) {
        tmp = atoi(buf);
        run_sum += tmp;
    }
    sprintf(buf, "%d", run_sum);
    write (pipe_ref, buf, sizeof(buf));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: first things first , check that the file open worked

Comment: `Reader` is writing 256 bytes to the pipe, but the parent process is only reading 10 bytes.

Comment: @Barmar I see. I will change that now

Comment: @pm100 added a test case, it opens correctly

Comment: `strcat("SHM_", my_array[i])` is UB. You can _not_ append to a string _constant_

Comment: @Barmar changed tmpbuf to only contain 10 bytes (which is the amount I need) and was given the same result

Comment: You can't concatenate characters to strings: `my_array[i] + '.' + 'c'`

Comment: Use `sprintf()` to format strings from components. E.g. `sprintf(command_name, "%s.c", my_array[i])`

Comment: @Barmar fixed the concat there as well, no change to output

Comment: @pm100 where do I add a null terminator?

Comment: @pm100 Actually, it will. He's using `write()` to send the whole C string, which has a null terminator. So `read()` will get the terminator.

Comment: It might help to _edit_ your question and post [more] complete code so we can download/build/run it.

Comment: It would help a lot if you used a debugger to determine which line is getting the bus error.

Comment: @Barmar The line that is giving the error has a comment above it stating which one it is

Comment: @CraigEstey I will link a github repository with the full code and makefile

Comment: you have to check the returns from shm_open and mmap

Comment: Pointers in shared memory won't work. Every process has different addresses.

Comment: We don't need the full code. We need the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. And you should post it here, not at a github repo that will change over time. Someone reading this question 5 years from now should be able to see the problem.

Comment: @pm100 done, no change in output

Comment: @Barmar I placed all of starter and reader in there, you shouldn't need any of the series files you can just place an empty main in there. the text file just has this as its entire body

07
3

Comment: I'm not going to try to extract the relevant parts. You want help, you do the work. Ideally you should be able to put all the relevant code in the question.

Comment: After building and running under `gdb`, in `Starter` at line 42: `if (i % j == 0) continue;` produces `SIGFPE` because `j` is _always_ zero on the first iteration.

Comment: @Barmar then go to my repository pal, it's literally easier for you to download the files with the correct names and extensions than to create files and copy my code into them. Then, whatever I change can be changed here publicly. If that's too much work... then I've done all I can.

Comment: I don't want to download your repo. I want you to write a question that will have lasting value for the site.

Comment: @CraigEstey ok I changed j to start at 1 instead of 0. Thanks!

Comment: There were so many things wrong with your code, I think this may be a little advanced for you.

Comment: I've added some debug `printf`. `voidarr` gets _non-null_ pointers from `mmap`. But, you're _only_ specifying `PROT_WRITE`. You need: `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE`. And, at the bad `printf`, `voidarr[1-2]` have been blasted to 0!

Comment: @CraigEstey ok I added that, I am working on installing a debugger as well to see why I am still getting this error in more detail

Comment: @CraigEstey I'm sorry, can you go into more detail as to what you mean "blasted to 0"? like its always calling to voidarr[0]?

Comment: After the `mmap` calls, `voidarr` looks like (e.g.) `{0x7ffff7fce000, 0x7fffffffdb28, 0x7fffffffdb24}`. But, at the bad `printf` they are: `{0x7ffff7fce000, 0x0, 0x0}`

Comment: Worse: After the `mmap` call, _any_ immediate deref of `voidarr[0]` produces `SIGBUS`. Originally, I had posted a comment about _not_ doing `mmap` over a `shm_open` return but deleted it. For whatever reason, the mapping is _not_ valid/usable even though it's non-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that after doing `shm_open`, doing `fstat` on the return value shows an `st_size` value of 0!

Initially, the descriptor from `shm_open` has zero size. It must be explicitly given a size. Note that just specifying 32 as a length to `mmap` does *not* cause the file to be expanded.

This must be done with `ftruncate`.

After the `shm_open` call, you need to do:

```
ftruncate(shms[i],32);
```

---

Here is a patch against your github repo. Even without that, it shows the changes needed:

```
diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
index 9ea673f..a478bf6 100644
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
@@ -1,29 +1,38 @@
 CC=gcc
 CFLAGS=-Wall -lrt
+CFLAGS += -g

-build: Starter HarmonicSeries HexagonalSeries Lucas Reader
+TARGETS = Starter HarmonicSeries HexagonalSeries Lucas Reader
+
+build: $(TARGETS)

 Starter: Starter.c
-   $(CC) -o Starter $(CFLAGS) Starter.c
+   $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) Starter.c

 HarmonicSeries: HarmonicSeries.c
-   $(CC) -o harmonicseries $(CFLAGS) HarmonicSeries.c
+   $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) HarmonicSeries.c

 HexagonalSeries: HexagonalSeries.c
-   $(CC) -o hexagonalseries $(CFLAGS) HexagonalSeries.c
+   $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) HexagonalSeries.c

 Lucas: Lucas.c
-   $(CC) -o lucas $(CFLAGS) Lucas.c
+   $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) Lucas.c

 Reader: Reader.c
-   $(CC) -o reader $(CFLAGS) Reader.c
+   $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) Reader.c

 clean:
-   rm -rf *.o Starter HarmonicSeries HexagonalSeries Lucas
+   rm -rf *.o $(TARGETS) gdbcmds

 test:
    ./Starter file_01.in

+gdb: gdbcmds
+   gdb -x gdbcmds ./Starter
+
+gdbcmds:
+   echo "set args file_01.in" > $@
+
 tar:
    tar -cvzf Anon-HW3.tar Starter.c Lucas.c HexagonalSeries.c HarmonicSeries.c Makefile README.txt

diff --git a/Starter.c b/Starter.c
index 31feae5..6ebfc35 100644
--- a/Starter.c
+++ b/Starter.c
@@ -6,6 +6,7 @@
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <sys/mman.h>
 #include <sys/shm.h>
+#include <sys/stat.h>

 //for testing
 #include <inttypes.h>
@@ -38,7 +39,7 @@ int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
         n = atoi(str);
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
-        for (int j = 0; j < i/2; j++) {
+        for (int j = 1; j < i/2; j++) {
             if (i % j == 0) continue;
             if (j == i/2-1) {
                 maxPrime = i;
@@ -63,7 +64,45 @@ int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         shms[i] = shm_open(my_array3[i], O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
+#if 1
+       if (shms[i] < 0) {
+           perror("shm_open");
+           exit(1);
+       }
+#endif
+
+#if 1
+       struct stat st;
+       fstat(shms[i],&st);
+       printf("DEBUG i=%d st_size=%zu\n",i,st.st_size);
+#endif
+
+// NOTE/FIX: at this point, st_size is zero!
+// need to provide some space
+#if 1
+       ftruncate(shms[i],32);
+       fstat(shms[i],&st);
+       printf("DEBUG i=%d st_size=%zu\n",i,st.st_size);
+#endif
+
+#if 0
         voidarr[i] = mmap(NULL, 32, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shms[i], 0);
+#else
+        voidarr[i] = mmap(NULL, 32, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shms[i], 0);
+       if (voidarr[i] == MAP_FAILED) {
+           perror("mmap");
+           exit(1);
+       }
+#endif
+
+       printf("DEBUG: i=%d shms=%d voidarr=%p my_array3='%s'\n",
+           i,shms[i],voidarr[i],my_array3[i]);
+
+// NOTE/BUG: this produces SIGBUS!!!
+       int probe = *(char *) voidarr[i];
+
+       printf("DEBUG/PROBE: probe=%d\n",probe);
+
         pidArray[i] = fork();
         if (pidArray[i] < 0) {
             fprintf(stderr, "Error running child process %s", my_array[i]);
```

---

Here is the output of the modified program:

```
./Starter file_01.in
Hello from reader[Starter][422287]: contents read from the read end pipe: 10
DEBUG i=0 st_size=0
DEBUG i=0 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=0 shms=4 voidarr=0x7f98e1e54000 my_array3='SHM_lucas'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter]: 422287 and ]
DEBUG i=1 st_size=0
DEBUG i=1 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=1 shms=5 voidarr=0x7f98e1e53000 my_array3='SHM_hexagonalseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter]: 422287 and ]
DEBUG i=2 st_size=0
DEBUG i=2 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=2 shms=6 voidarr=0x7f98e1e52000 my_array3='SHM_harmonicseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_lucas" with FD: 4
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_hexagonalseries" with FD: 5
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_harmonicseries" with FD: 6
[Starter][422287]: contents read from the read end pipe: 10
DEBUG i=0 st_size=0
DEBUG i=0 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=0 shms=4 voidarr=0x7f98e1e54000 my_array3='SHM_lucas'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
DEBUG i=1 st_size=32
DEBUG i=1 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=1 shms=5 voidarr=0x7f98e1e53000 my_array3='SHM_hexagonalseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter]: 422287 and ]
DEBUG i=2 st_size=32
DEBUG i=2 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=2 shms=6 voidarr=0x7f98e1e52000 my_array3='SHM_harmonicseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_lucas" with FD: 4
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_hexagonalseries" with FD: 5
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_harmonicseries" with FD: 6
[Starter][422287]: contents read from the read end pipe: 10
DEBUG i=0 st_size=0
DEBUG i=0 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=0 shms=4 voidarr=0x7f98e1e54000 my_array3='SHM_lucas'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter]: 422287 and ]
DEBUG i=1 st_size=0
DEBUG i=1 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=1 shms=5 voidarr=0x7f98e1e53000 my_array3='SHM_hexagonalseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
DEBUG i=2 st_size=32
DEBUG i=2 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=2 shms=6 voidarr=0x7f98e1e52000 my_array3='SHM_harmonicseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_lucas" with FD: 4
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_hexagonalseries" with FD: 5
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_harmonicseries" with FD: 6
[Starter][422287]: contents read from the read end pipe: 10
DEBUG i=0 st_size=0
DEBUG i=0 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=0 shms=4 voidarr=0x7f98e1e54000 my_array3='SHM_lucas'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
DEBUG i=1 st_size=32
DEBUG i=1 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=1 shms=5 voidarr=0x7f98e1e53000 my_array3='SHM_hexagonalseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
DEBUG i=2 st_size=0
DEBUG i=2 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=2 shms=6 voidarr=0x7f98e1e52000 my_array3='SHM_harmonicseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_lucas" with FD: 4
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_hexagonalseries" with FD: 5
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_harmonicseries" with FD: 6
[Starter][422287]: contents read from the read end pipe: 10
DEBUG i=0 st_size=0
DEBUG i=0 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=0 shms=4 voidarr=0x7f98e1e54000 my_array3='SHM_lucas'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
DEBUG i=1 st_size=32
DEBUG i=1 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=1 shms=5 voidarr=0x7f98e1e53000 my_array3='SHM_hexagonalseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
DEBUG i=2 st_size=0
DEBUG i=2 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=2 shms=6 voidarr=0x7f98e1e52000 my_array3='SHM_harmonicseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter]: 422287 and ]
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_lucas" with FD: 4
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_hexagonalseries" with FD: 5
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_harmonicseries" with FD: 6
[Starter][422287]: contents read from the read end pipe: 10
DEBUG i=0 st_size=0
DEBUG i=0 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=0 shms=4 voidarr=0x7f98e1e54000 my_array3='SHM_lucas'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter]: 422287 and ]
DEBUG i=1 st_size=0
DEBUG i=1 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=1 shms=5 voidarr=0x7f98e1e53000 my_array3='SHM_hexagonalseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
DEBUG i=2 st_size=32
DEBUG i=2 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=2 shms=6 voidarr=0x7f98e1e52000 my_array3='SHM_harmonicseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter]: 422287 and ]
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_lucas" with FD: 4
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_hexagonalseries" with FD: 5
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_harmonicseries" with FD: 6
[Starter][422287]: contents read from the read end pipe: 10
DEBUG i=0 st_size=0
DEBUG i=0 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=0 shms=4 voidarr=0x7f98e1e54000 my_array3='SHM_lucas'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
DEBUG i=1 st_size=32
DEBUG i=1 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=1 shms=5 voidarr=0x7f98e1e53000 my_array3='SHM_hexagonalseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter]: 422287 and ]
DEBUG i=2 st_size=32
DEBUG i=2 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=2 shms=6 voidarr=0x7f98e1e52000 my_array3='SHM_harmonicseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter]: 422287 and ]
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_lucas" with FD: 4
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_hexagonalseries" with FD: 5
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_harmonicseries" with FD: 6
[Starter][422287]: contents read from the read end pipe: 10
DEBUG i=0 st_size=0
DEBUG i=0 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=0 shms=4 voidarr=0x7f98e1e54000 my_array3='SHM_lucas'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter]: 422287 and ]
DEBUG i=1 st_size=0
DEBUG i=1 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=1 shms=5 voidarr=0x7f98e1e53000 my_array3='SHM_hexagonalseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter]: 422287 and ]
DEBUG i=2 st_size=0
DEBUG i=2 st_size=32
DEBUG: i=2 shms=6 voidarr=0x7f98e1e52000 my_array3='SHM_harmonicseries'
DEBUG/PROBE: probe=0
[Starter]: 422287 and ]
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_lucas" with FD: 4
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_hexagonalseries" with FD: 5
[Starter][422287] : Created Shared memory "SHM_harmonicseries" with FD: 6
```